# Why do I always get the same result when using function and contains in fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to do a basic calculation by calling a function using contains

```
Program main
implicit none
integer*8 Nmax,i
Parameter (Nmax=5)
real*8 x, f(Nmax), n

do i=1, Nmax
    n=i
f=func(n,Nmax)
    write(*,*) f(i)
end do 

Contains
   real*8 function func(x,Nmax)
   integer*8 Nmax,i
   real*8 x, f(Nmax)

    do i=1, Nmax-1
        f(i)=i**2d0-4d0*i-7d0
    end do
   end function
end program main

 I get this result:
 -9.255963134931783E+061
 -9.255963134931783E+061
 -9.255963134931783E+061
 -9.255963134931783E+061
 -9.255963134931783E+061
```

I think I'm making the wrong variable definitions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your program.

First, you probably meant to write:

`f(i)=func(n,Nmax)`

in the main program. Without the subscript you assign the same value to each element of the array. You might think that explains the results, but it doesn't as you'd still see what you expect.

Another problem is highlighted by the following warning I get when I compile your code with Intel Fortran:

`t.f90(14): warning #6178: The return value of this FUNCTION has not been defined.   [FUNC]
   real*8 function func(x,Nmax)
-------------------^`

You never assign the value of func, so you get whatever garbage happens to be in the return register.

The function you have isn't really what you want, either. You probably want one that computes and returns a scalar (single) value and hence there is no need for an array inside func.

A third problem is that func is ignoring the n argument (which, contrary to convention, you have declared as a real.)

If you want a loop in the main program, have the function compute and return a single result based on the argument passed to it. There is no need to pass both the loop index and nmax each time. Other options, slightly more advanced, would be to keep the array assignment in the main program but do away with the loop there and either have the function return an array or make the function ELEMENTAL. I will leave it as an exercise for you once you figure out what you really intend here.

Lastly, I would discourage you from using nonstandard syntax such as "real*8". Please learn about KIND specifiers and the SELECTED_REAL_KIND intrinsic function.